# rotate a set of images in an ellipse

Tags: javascript

How can I rotate a set of images in an ellipse without using jquery? how to get each point on a ellipse at some center(x,y)point

Comment: Is the number of images fixed??

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of any point on an ellipse which center is (x,y) are (x + a cos(c), y + b sin(c) )  with a and b defining the size of the ellipse, and c defining the angle in [0,2pi].

For n images, the angles will be of the form (2pi/n)i + delta, with i in [0,n] and delta the movement from the original position, which you will use for the animation.

Comment: can u please give me a sample on this.